# How can i add multiple user roles to single pathMatcher/Route in Spring WebFlux Security(Reactive Spring Security) Config?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

i have a route that needs to authenticated for more than one user. performing integration testing on **spring cloud gateway** service to test all the routes security working as expected or not. how can i add more than 1 user role to single pathMatcher/route?

Using Spring Boot 2.1.6, Spring Cloud Finchely.SR2, Spring Cloud Gateway, Spring WebFlux Security(Reactive Spring Security)

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

http.csrf().disable()        
           .formLogin().disable()
           .logout().disable()
           .authorizeExchange()
           .pathMatchers(prefix + "/publish/**")
           .hasRole("XYZ_ROLE") //Here i want to add more than one user role
           .anyExchange()
           .authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

After looking through the spring security source code and github issues i found out that `hasAnyRole` and `hasAnyAuthority` has been [implemented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6306) for spring security for webflux and is **planned to be released in Spring security v5.2.0**.

**As of writing current stable version is 5.1.6** but the 5.2.0 is in milestone 4 so it should be released very soon. You can use the snapshot version of 5.2.0 if needed.

The only other current option if not using the snapshot is to implement your own custom `ReactiveAuthorizationManager` and use the [ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec#access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec.Access.html#access-org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager-) function.

**OLD ANSWER ONLY APPLICABLE TO STANDARD SPRING SECURITY NOT WEBFLUX:**

You can try out the [`hasAnyRole(String... roles)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html#hasAnyRole-java.lang.String...-)

Comment: am using spring webflux security, there is no such method available.

Comment: sorry for the late update, saw that you found a workaround. I did some digging and i have updated my answer with some more information.

Answer (score 2):

after digging the rabbit hole, i found solution to **Authorize for multiple roles** using Reactive Spring Security. find the solution below:

````
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

http.csrf().disable()        
           .formLogin().disable()
           .logout().disable()
           .authorizeExchange()
                     .pathMatchers(prefix + "/publish/**").access((mono, context) -> mono
                                            .map(auth -> auth.getAuthorities().stream()

//Authorizing for multiple user roles                       
.filter(e -> (e.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ABC") || e.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_XYZ"))) 
                                            .count() > 0)
                                            .map(AuthorizationDecision::new))

           .anyExchange()
           .authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }
}```
````

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something else actually. I was looking for authorizing a pathMatcher according to a specific custom header key and value. Your code snippet helped me to understand the `access` method. The `context` parameter holds the `ServerExchange` object which internally holds the `ServerHttpRequest` object. And I was able to extract the header from there. Thanks again!