# Require multiple authorities in Spring ServerHTTPSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Security with Spring Cloud Gateway and need to configure routes that require multiple authorities. So far I'm only able to specify an individual authority per route:

```
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain apiHttpSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        http.securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/api/**"))
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                    .pathMatchers("/api/developer/**").hasAuthority("Developer")
                    .pathMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority("Admin")
                    .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor())));

        return http.build();
    }
```

How can I extend this so certain routes require more than one authority? Such as:

```
.pathMatchers("/api/example/**/).hasAuthority("Developer").hasAuthority("SeniorDev")
```

The `.hasAnyAuthority("Developer", "SeniorDev")` method exists and works as an OR statement but I don't see a method available for an AND statement.

Answer (score -1):

you can just use below code :

```java
.antMatchers("/api/example/**").access("hasAuthority('developer') and hasAuthority('admin')")
```

**UPDATED************

try this solution for ServerHttpSecurity

```java
.pathMatchers("/api/example/**").access((mono, context) -> mono
                                .map(auth -> auth.getAuthorities().stream()
                                        .filter(e -> (e.getAuthority().equals("ADMIN") && e.getAuthority().equals("DEVELOPER"))).count() > 0)
                                .map(AuthorizationDecision::new))
```

Comment: `.antMatchers()` is not a method available on exchanges. I believe that can only be used with `HttpSecurity` vs. `ServerHttpSecurity`

Comment: yes so says right please try the new solution and  see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633276/how-can-i-add-multiple-user-roles-to-single-pathmatcher-route-in-spring-webflux